# How to concatenate 2D arrays on the fly in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dynamic, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate 2D arrays horizontally using numpy in a dynamic way. Starting from an empty array I want to add 2D arrays depending on the if condition outcome. I don't know the final dimension so I cannot define anything before the loop starts. Assuming I have the 2D arrays called A,B,C:

```
X = np.array([])
for name in modules:
   if name = 'AAA':
      X = np.append(X,A, axis = 1)
   if name = 'BBB'
      X = np.append(X,B, axis = 1)
   if name = 'CCC'
      X = np.append(X,C, axis = 1)
```

After reading how np.append works I realized why this solution is wrong. Is there an easy way to produce concatenation on the fly? N:B: I know the number of columns and rows of A,B,C (they have the same number of rows) but I cannot know how many matrices will be concatenated since all is depending on the if conditions. The concatenation order is important and should be as reported in the code.

Comment: Collect the arrays in a list, and do one `np.concatenate` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because at first, `X` does not have the same number of rows as `A`, `B` or `C`, you can not append `X` with any of them. Here is a small tweak:

```
X = None
for name in modules:
   if name = 'AAA':
      X = np.append(X,A, axis = 1) if X is not None else A
   if name = 'BBB'
      X = np.append(X,B, axis = 1) if X is not None else B
   if name = 'CCC'
      X = np.append(X,C, axis = 1) if X is not None else C
```

Hope this would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a dictionary which functions as a lookup-table, matching the names with the arrays.

```
mapper = {'AAA': A,
          'BBB': B,
          'CCC': C}

X = np.hstack([mapper[name] for name in modules])
```

Comment: He wants `hstack` or `concatenate` with `axis=1`.  Other than that it's a cleaner solution.